# How to access arrayLists from other classes (possibly in other packages)

Tags: java, minecraft

I need to access an ArrayList that I've created in my me.tylercreator.FallenSurv main class from other classes in other packages.

I have different packages , but i need every class to be able to access to certain ArraysList from a class.

I've tried to declare them as public static , but with that i can access them from other class only in the same file.

```
package me.tylercreator.fallensurv.tracer;

public class MovementTracer implements Listener {

    public static ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static ArrayList<Block> blockplaced = new ArrayList<Block>();

    public static ArrayList<String> onlineplayerList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I need that to be accessed from other classes in other packages like package me.tylercreator.fallensurv.spawnmodifier

Comment: Do you have a sample piece of code which fails to access the array list?

Comment: `MovementTracer.ar.get(0);`

Comment: Please try to understand the OOPs concept first. Try to understand how access modifiers and specifiers works,  I guarantee you will get your answers yourself.

Having said that, as npinti mentioned, you might have missed import statement and as RobOhRob mentioned, you could access the Arraylist.

Comment: @RobOhRob: My main concern is that the OP might be missing some import statements.

Comment: Tank you guys, Eclipse autocompiler was being stupid and wasn't letting me do MovementTracer.ar , now I got it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you , but I just figured out that my Eclipse application was being stupid and didn't let me write MovementTracer.ar (for unknown reasons), now it works and I'm accessing the array from different packages.!

I'll soon switch to IntelliJ IDEA , which in my opinion is better.

Comment: The IDE is completely irrelevant to the `MovementTracer.ar` syntax. You probably simply didn't have the `import` in place. Ctrl+Shift+O to 'Organize Imports' in Eclipse would help, which is Alt+Enter in IntelliJ IDEA.